# Ruby on Rails - couldn't find file 'admin-lte' with type 'application/javascript'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I got this error message after I add this line in application.js and install via `bundle install`.

```
couldn't find file 'admin-lte' with type 'application/javascript'
```

application.js

```
//= require admin-lte
```

Resource: https://github.com/shine60vn/adminlte-rails

Answer (score 1):

Restart Rails server to make sure gem is installed and js file is served to the asset pipeline.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking Ask Question. You can also add a bounty to draw more attention to this question once you have enough reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me.

What happens when you do `gem which adminlte-rails`?

Double check your gem source / reinstall it.